# jQuery Custom Grid like masorny layout

Tags: jquery, grid

I am trying to make a custom grid like masorny layout for a web site, so i thought for approaching a layout like masorny with 3 columns to create 3 div's that will work as the parent divs and inside to append the children div's depends on id number.

The html mark up :

```
// Parent DIVs

<body>

  <div id="column1"></div>
  <div id="column2"></div>
  <div id="column3"></div>

</body>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var items = 32;

    for (var i=1;i<=items.length;i++) {

        if (i % 3 ==0) {
           $('#column3').append('<div class="children" id="'+i+'">'+i+'</div>');
        }
        else if (i % 2 ==0) {
           $('#column2').append('<div class="children" id="'+i+'">'+i+'</div>');
        }
        else {
           $('#column1').append('<div class="children" id="'+i+'">'+i+'</div>');
       }

    }

});
```

I've got the result i want but not as the desired order.

The order i want is like:

1,2,3

4,5,6

7,8,9

10,11,12

...

but instead i've got something like:

1,2,3

5,4,6

7,8,9

11,10,12

check my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7u4rqxxt/

note i dont want to use masorny.js or something similar, i want to make my own custom.

Any ideas, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with the way you ordered your column :

> 5 % 2 = 1, so it will be display on the column 1

I change the name of column3 by column0

```
#column1,
#column2,
#column0
```

and

```
<div id="column1"></div>
<div id="column2"></div>
<div id="column0"></div>
```

and i sort by `i%3` :

```
for (var i=1;i<=32;i++) {
$('#column' + (i % 3)).append('<div class="children">'+i+'</div>');
}
```

check the example here :

http://jsfiddle.net/7u4rqxxt/3/